# how to fix this programme

Tags: c++, arrays

> Given an array `A`, find the highest unique element in array `A`. Unique element means that element should present only once in the array.
>
> Input:
>
> First line of input contains N, size of array A. Next line contains N
>   space separated elements of array A.
>
> Output:
>
> Print highest unique number of array A. If there is no any such
>   element present in array then print -1.
>
> Constraints:
>
> ```
> 1 ≤ N ≤ 106 0 ≤ Ai ≤ 109
> ```
>
> SAMPLE INPUT
>
> ```
> 5 9 8 8 9 5
> ```
>
> SAMPLE OUTPUT
>
> ```
> 5
> ```
>
> Explanation
>
> In array A: 9 occur two times. 8 occur two times. 5 occur once hence the answer is 5.

Can you explain what is wrong with this code?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  int a[n], i, max = -99;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> a[i];
  }
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (a[i] > max) {
      max = a[i];
      cout << max;
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (max == a[i]) {
      break;
    } else {
      // cout<<"-1";
    }
    max =
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your title question is different than the question in the post. What's the real question?

Comment: `std::sort`, `std::unique`, and `std::max_element` will do this for you.

Comment: `int a[n]` is variable-length array. C++ doesn't allow this. Use a std::vector

Answer (score 2):

There's a few problems here (right now it won't even compile at `max =`).  But the algorithmic problem is this:  the second for loop finds the maximum *before* rejecting duplicate entries.  The reverse is needed.  First reject duplicates (say, by setting them to -99), *then* find the max of what is left over.